# Display on a view fields values from 2 joined forms - Lotus Notes

Tags: join, lotus-notes

I have 2 forms , form1 and form2 with a common field commofield .
I need records (documents) that have the  same vale on this  commofield  (all records that form1.commofield  = form2.commofield ) . Is tha possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes (aka IBM Notes and HCL Notes) is not relational. It can't display data from two documents in a single view entry.

There are a number of ways that people have worked around this over the last 25 years. The pretty much all involve lookup formulas and/or agents that populate all the data from the different sources into a single document.

Answer (score 0):

@DBColum seems more close to my case ..

Thanks you.